# CakePHP - Custom validation function for the Uploader plugin

Tags: cakephp, behavior, uploader

I want to use the custom validation functions in the Uploader behaviour, width and height, to create a new custom validation function which tests if the image is square. So when I am using the behaviour in the model this is how I am using the File Validation functions. I have outlined what I want to do below in the my SquareValidation function as well.

```
    public $actsAs = array(         
        'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'extension' => array(
                    'value' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'),
                    'error' => 'You can only upload images'
                ),
                'mySquareValidation'
            )
    )

    public function mySquareValidation () {
       return width = height;
       // WHAT IS THE RIGHT SYNTAX TO ACCESS WIDTH AND HEIGHT BEHAVIOUR FUNCTIONS?
    }
```

But how do I access those core (to the behaviour) validation functions inside a custom validation function and use them to check if the submitted file is square (I want to allow any height/width combo). I know that to call a core validation function (to CakePHP) I would for example simply use:

```
Validation::rule($this->data['field'])
```

So how do I do the same for the core validation functions belonging to the behaviour? And when I have created the custom validation function, do I then execute the function in the behaviour array just like I would in the validation array (like in my example)?

Reference: Uploader docs - http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#validating-against-a-model

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting the validation function inside the Behavior?
Also, I guess you mean

```
return width == height;
```